# How to append in multidimensional arrays using python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, append

I have two 1-D arrays:

```
tminus = [219 220 225 226 227 332]
tplus = [221 222 227 228 229 334]
```

And a 2-D array:

```
t = [[222 224 228 244],[264 280 283 255 346]]
```

How do I append `t` for the values that are in between `tminus` and `tplus`? I am trying to keep `t` as the 2-D array. I tried:

```
time = []
for k in range(len(tminus)):
    for i in range(len(t)):
        for j in range(len(t[i])):
            if tminus[k] <= t[j] <= tplus[k]:
                time.append(t[j])
print time
```

But, all I get is the empty list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want the values of t to be between the minimum of tminus and the maximum of tplus?

Comment: So for every value of t, I want to see if that one value is in between the values of tminus and tplus. So for t[0][0], I want to see if its between tminus[0] and tplus[0] and then if its in between tminus[1] and tplus[1] etc. and if it is then, the value for t is appended into time.

Comment: what result do you expect from the given inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
if tminus[k] <= t[j] <= tplus[k]:
```

Note that you call `t[j]`, which will find the `j`th element inside of `t`. However, `t[j]` will always be a list, as `t` is a 2D array.

To iterate over the sublists(`t[i]`) inside of `t`, use

```
t[i][j]
```

This gets the `j`th element in the `i`th element in `t`.

For example, if `i` is 0, and `j` is also 0, `t[j]` would return `[222, 224, 228, 244]`, and you can't compare an `int` to a `list`. Instead, `t[i][j]` would return `222`, which is what you were aiming for.

Because you also want the shape of `t` to stay the same, create a temporary variable (`appendList`), append values to that, then append the whole list to `t`.

However, with your current code, it will create unnecessary lists, as it will create one for every element in `tminus`. To avoid this, you can switch the order of the for loops, so that it only creates `appendList`. Also, this can cause a single number to be appended multiple times, so we pass it into `set()` to remove duplicates, and then pass it into `list()` to turn it into a list again.

Updated code:

```
tminus = [219, 220, 225, 226, 227, 332]
tplus = [221, 222, 227, 228, 229, 334]
t = [[222, 224, 228, 244],[264, 280, 283, 255, 346]]

time = []
for i in range(len(t)): # Iterate over t
    appendList = [] # Stores values to be appended to time
    for j in range(len(t[i])): # Iterate over the sublists in t
        for k in range(len(tminus)): # Iterate over tminus
            if tminus[k] <= t[i][j] <= tplus[k]: # Check value
                appendList.append(t[i][j]) # Append value to appendList
    appendList = list(set(appendList)) # Remove duplicates
    time.append(appendList) # Append entire list to time
print(time)
```

This gives the result:
`[[228, 222], []]`

Caveats:
- If `t` has repeating elements, only one of them will stay
- Order is lost when passing into `set()`

Comment: but is the way I wrote the loop the correct way to write it? For every value of t, I want to see if that one value is in between the values of tminus and tplus. So for t[0][0], I want to see if its between tminus[0] and tplus[0] and then if its in between tminus[1] and tplus[1] etc. and if it is then, the value for t is appended into time. I would like the t array to still be 2-D

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is what you are looking for but from my understanding this should solve the problem.

```
index = 0
for i in range(0,len(t)):
    for j in range(0,len(t[index])):
        if max(tminus) <= t[i][j] <= min(tplus):
            time.append(t[i][j])
    index +=1
return time
```